# Errorneous output while reading File in C

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write a string to a file and then read the string and output the string written into the file.
For example

```
INPUT (Input Name)
FalconHawk

OUTPUT
Hi FalconHawk! Have a great day!
```

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){

char n[10],r[1000];
FILE *fptr,*fpt;

scanf("%s",n);                        //Input name

fptr=fopen("welcome.txt","w");
fprintf(fptr,"%s",n);                 //Write to file
fclose(fptr);

fpt=fopen("welcome.txt","r");
fscanf(fpt,"%s",r);                 
printf("Hi %s! Have a good day.",r);  //Output file content
fclose(fpt);
}
```

But because of some reason I am getting an output like

```
INPUT (Input Name)
FalconHawk

OUTPUT
HiHi FalconHawk! Have a great day!   //"Hi" is getting printed two times
```

On replacing "Hi" with "Welcome" I am getting an output like

```
OUTPUT
WelcomeWelcome FalconHawk! Have a great day!   //"Welcome" is getting printed two times.
```

What is causing this issue?

Comment: But, now it is giving output like: Hi FalconHawk! Have a good day!FalconHawk      (name is getting printed at the end of output)

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is too small and there's no room for the terminating `null` byte, therefore, your code invokes undefined behavior. If you want to read 10 characters, then this is how you should do it

```
char input[11];
if (scanf("%10s", input) == 1) {
    // Safely use `input' here
}
```

And if you want to read an entire line of text from *stdin* then use `fgets()` instead

```
if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL) {
    // Safely use `input' here
}
```

---

Strings in *c* always need an extra byte of space to store the terminating `'\0'`, read a basic tutorial on strings in *c* to learn how they work and how to treat them.

Comment: But, now it is giving output like: Hi FalconHawk! Have a good day!FalconHawk      (name is getting printed at the end of output)

Comment: @FalconHawk You need to explicitly flush the output buffer or, add a `\n` at the end of the `printf()` format string.

Comment: @FalconHawk if you're on linux use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) in combination with *gdb* and you will understand closely what is it that the code is doing and why the output is not the one that you expect.